# Cannot init panamax on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: user-interface, docker, vagrant, init

Currently looking for Docker GUI to help me manage the installed container inside my Local computer (Ubuntu 17.04 laptop), Then decide to chose panamax as my choice, but unfortunately I unable to init the Panamax, I keep asking me to install Vagrant which is already installed on my local computer.

here is my local machine configuration:

```
███████╗ ██████╗  █████████╗ ██████╗  ██████████╗ ██████╗  ██╗  ██╗

██╔══██║  ╚═══██╗ ███╗  ███║  ╚═══██╗ ██║ ██╔ ██║  ╚═══██╗ ╚██╗██╔╝

██   ██║ ███████║ ███║  ███║ ███████║ ██║╚██║ ██║ ███████║  ╚███╔╝ 

███████╝ ███████║ ███║  ███║ ███████║ ██║╚██║ ██║ ███████║  ██╔██╗ 

██║      ███████║ ███║  ███║ ███████║ ██║╚██║ ██║ ███████║ ██╔╝ ██╗

╚═╝      ╚══════╝ ╚══╝  ╚══╝ ╚══════╝ ╚═╝ ╚═╝ ╚═╝ ╚══════╝ ╚═╝  ╚═╝



CenturyLink Labs - http://www.centurylinklabs.com/

Checking if required software is installed.

Please install vagrant version 1.6.3 or newer 

(https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html).

╭─yusuf@yusuf-berkarya ~/test  

╰─➤  vboxmanage --version && vagrant -v

5.2.8r121009

Vagrant 2.0.3


╭─yusuf@yusuf-berkarya ~/test  

╰─➤  lsb_release -a


No LSB modules are available.

Distributor ID: Ubuntu

Description:    Ubuntu 17.10

Release:    17.10

Codename:   artful
```

Any help could be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command sudo apt-get install lsb-core 
if issue still persists downgrade your vagrant version and check if the issue is resolved.

Comment: Hi, great, I almost there... got another error: Vagrant 1.6 or newer installed.
Virtualbox 4.3 or newer installed.

A different VM with name panamax-vm has been created already. Please re-install or delete panamax-vm VM and try again.

Comment: Please do the following command to remove the old vm:

vagrant destroy

Reference documentation for vagrant: https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/cli/destroy.html

Comment: I need to dowgrade the Virtualbox too I guess: Vagrant has detected that you have a version of VirtualBox installed
that is not supported. Please install one of the supported versions
listed below to use Vagrant:

4.0, 4.1, 4.2, 4.3

Comment: unfortunately my ubuntu 17.04 does not support Virtualbox 4.3 ... does it means Panamax is no longer  running on the latest version of ubuntu?

Comment: I'm giving up, no working solution for this issue, moving to another application then.. trying to install https://dockstation.io/ now